# MongoDB shardsvr option?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

As per [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#shardsvr), the default value for `shardsvr` option is `false`:

> Set this value to true to configure this mongod instance as a shard in
>   a partitioned cluster. The default port for these instances is 27018.
>   The only affect of shardsvr is to change the port number.

It seems that `shardsvr` is required to configure an instance as a shard. But then it says that *the only affect is to change the port number*.

Why I need to change the port this way? There is already the `port` option...

```
mongod --port 27019 --dbpath /data/shard1
mongod --shardsvr --port 27019 --dbpath /data/shard1
```

Comment: shardsvr option is *not* required to use mongod as a shard.

Comment: The link is broken and the current version's sharding configuration is vastly different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This answer is no longer valid

See comments.

---

<strike>No, you don't *need* to change the port through `--shardsvr` option. Also you don't need to change port *at all*. You can assemble a cluster of `mongod` instances with their default ports.</strike>

<strike>The purpose of port changing, as I understand it, is to lower chances of you connecting to a shard directly. In a cluster setup, you're supposed to be working through a `mongos` router.</strike>

Comment: If i can change the port with `port` option, why I need to use the `shardsvr` option instead? Imagine a local configuration for testing, with mongos, config server and shards running on the same machine.

Comment: @Gremo: you don't need to use `--shardsvr` at all. It's just there for convenience.

Comment: As of 3.4, --shardsvr is now required on mongod instances which are part of a shard. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4/#membership-awareness